# Searching MySQL with Now() always returns true

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
| rsid | rsuser  | rsintime         | rsouttime        | rsroom |
| ---- | ------- | ---------------- | ---------------- | ------ |
|    1 | Nick S  | 10/14/2014 11:17 | 10/14/2014 12:18 |    1   |
|    2 | Mike G  | 10/15/2014 10:18 | 10/15/2014 11:19 |    1   |
|    3 | Chuck M | 10/14/2014 21:56 | 10/14/2014 22:56 |    1   |
|    4 | Jake B  | 10/26/2014 22:14 | 10/26/2014 23:15 |    1   |
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("0.0.0.0","roomapp","hi","roomapp");
$testschedulesql = "SELECT (NOW() > rsintime AND NOW() < rsouttime) as res_rm from raRmSchedule";
$testscheduleqry = mysqli_query($con, $testschedulesql);
$testschedule = mysqli_num_rows($testscheduleqry);
$testscheduletext = mysqli_fetch_array($testscheduleqry);
echo $testschedule;
if($testschedule > 0){
    echo 'Busy';
}
else{
    echo 'Not';
}
?>
```

However, $testschedule always returns the total rows.  I want it to return only rows where the current time is within an in/out time.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the data types of `rsintime` and `rsouttime`?  If they are not a date/time data type, then you should fix the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `where` clause:

```
SELECT rm.*
from raRmSchedule
WHERE (NOW() > rsintime AND NOW() < rsouttime)
```

To count the number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from raRmSchedule
WHERE (NOW() > rsintime AND NOW() < rsouttime)
```

This returns one row with one column.  It will be `0` if there are no matches.

Your version returns one row for each row in the table.  There will be one column with a value of `0` or `1`, depending on whether the condition matches.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will give you all rows, as what you are selecting is the boolean value of an expression.

I think what you want is giving the query a WHERE clause to filter the time you're needing.

Something like 
Select * from raRMSchedule where (now() > rsintime and now() < rsouttime).